# функционал jade/pug в jinja2(Nunjucks)

Tags: jade, jinja2

В jade я подключаю блоки с помощью миксинов

```
mixin navbar()
+b.NAV.navbar&attributes(attributes)
    block

+navbar
   p | some text
```

На выходе будет

```
 <nav><p>some text</p></nav>
```

Как в jinja2(Nunjucks) реализовать похожий функционал?

Answer (score 0):

```
           {% import "mixins/_mixins.html" as mixins %}      

           Input: macro/mixin  
              {% macro navbar %}
{%
        set seq = [
        {sometxt: 'lorem1'},
        {sometxt: 'lorem2'},
        {sometxt: 'lorem3'},
        {sometxt: 'lorem4'},
        {sometxt: 'lorem5'},
        {sometxt: 'lorem6'}
        ]
        %}
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in seq %}
                           <li><a href="#">{{item.sometxt}}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                {% endmacro %}

           Usage: {{mixins.navbar()}}

           Output:
           <nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><p>lorem1</p></li>
                    <li><p>lorem2</p></li>
                    <li><p>lorem3</p></li>
                    <li><p>lorem4</p></li>
                    <li><p>lorem5</p></li>
                    <li><p>lorem6</p></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```